# Absolute & Relative

Tags: html, css, css-position

I've been playing with both and I still can't seem to grasp the idea of them.

When I'm trying to make everything stay centered no matter what screen resolution you are looking at, I usually put in width with 0 auto. BUT - If I have the same property with absolute, it completely ignores this value and does not work.

So how exactly am I supposed to position an image on TOP of another image while making sure to keep it all centered for all screen resolutions as WELL as not using absolute?

EDIT: I'm trying to get the little news widget and the teamspeak widget to stay in the middle of the body.

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="page-wrap">
    <div id="header">
        <img src="images/header.png" />
    </div>
    <img src="images/navbar.png" />
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="http://www.voyage-us.com">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.voyage-us.com/xenforo/upload/index.php">Forums</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Members</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Streams</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="mainbody">
        <img src="images/mainbody.png" /></div>

    <div class="news1">
        <img src="images/news1.png" /></div>

    <div class="teamspeak">  <!--Teamspeak IMG-->
        <img src="images/teamspeak.png" /></div>

    <div id="ts3viewer_1037062" /></div>  <!-- Teamspeak Widget -->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tsviewer.com/short_expire/js/ts3viewer_loader.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        var ts3v_url_1 = "http://www.tsviewer.com/ts3viewer.php?ID=1037062&text=000000&text_size=12&text_family=2&js=1&text_s_color=ffffff&text_s_weight=bold&text_s_style=normal&text_s_variant=normal&text_s_decoration=none&text_s_color_h=ffffff&text_s_weight_h=bold&text_s_style_h=normal&text_s_variant_h=normal&text_s_decoration_h=underline&text_i_color=ffffff&text_i_weight=normal&text_i_style=normal&text_i_variant=normal&text_i_decoration=none&text_i_color_h=ffffff&text_i_weight_h=normal&text_i_style_h=normal&text_i_variant_h=normal&text_i_decoration_h=underline&text_c_color=ffffff&text_c_weight=normal&text_c_style=normal&text_c_variant=normal&text_c_decoration=none&text_c_color_h=ffffff&text_c_weight_h=normal&text_c_style_h=normal&text_c_variant_h=normal&text_c_decoration_h=underline&text_u_color=ffffff&text_u_weight=bold&text_u_style=normal&text_u_variant=normal&text_u_decoration=none&text_u_color_h=ffffff&text_u_weight_h=bold&text_u_style_h=normal&text_u_variant_h=normal&text_u_decoration_h=none";
        ts3v_display.init(ts3v_url_1, 1037062, 100);
        -->
        </script>

    <div id="footer">
        <p>&copy;2014 Rythmn Designs<p>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body
{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
background: url("http://puu.sh/6RlKi.png")
}

.clear
{
clear:both;
}

#page-wrap
{
width: 1019px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#header
{
width:100%;
text-align: center;
display: block;
}

#nav
{
height: 0.1px;
list-style: none;
padding-left: 14px;
text-align: center;
padding-bottom: 0px;
margin: -14px;
margin-top: -15px;
}

#nav li a
{
position:relative;
top: -12px;
display: block;
width: 100px;
float: left;
color: white;
font-size:  14.09px;
text-decoration: none;
font-family:"BankGothic Md BT"
}

#nav li a:hover, #nav li a:active
{
color: red;
}

#mainbody
{
vertical-align:top;
position:relative
}

.news1
{
position: absolute;
top: 435px;
right: 815px
}

.teamspeak
{
position: absolute;
top: 435px;
right: 470px

}

#ts3viewer_1037062
{
position:absolute;
top: 465px;
right: 478px;
width: 290px;
height:190px;
overflow:auto;
}

#footer
{
background: #181818;
color: white;
padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
text-transform: uppercase;
border-top: 15px solid #828080;
text-align: center;
font-family:"BankGothic Md BT";
font-size:  12px;
position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Please post your HTML and the CSS you've got so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go about it a different way and use nested `<DIV>` tags, such as:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
    </div>
</div>
```

And then add your images to the CSS. See e.g. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j2RPn/).

Answer (score 0):

For an absolutely positioned element, assuming a fixed width

```
left: 50%;
margin-left: -[width/2];
```

`left` puts its left border in the middle of the screen; negative `margin` pulls it back to the left by half its width, centering it.

---

`absolute` positioning allows `top, right, bottom, left` properties to be defined relative to the window or to a containing element.

`relative` allows the same properties to be defined relative to where the element would normally appear in the document flow.